# How can I change the layout of unread emails in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to change the display of unread emails in Outlook 2010? I find that "bold" is not enough for me. Can I add a color or something more attracting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook select the Inbox.
Choose Arrange By from the View menu.
Select Current View from the resulting submenu.
Select Customize Current View.
Click Automatic Formatting.
At this point, several options are (probably) checked. Whatever options you leave checked will reflect the changes you make in subsequent steps. If you want to change the format only for unread messages, uncheck everything but the Unread Messages option.
Click Font.
Specify the formats you want to apply.
Click OK three times.

(Referenced: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/determine-how-outlook-displays-unread-messages/845)